# Rails Model Associations when nesting - Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Perhaps I am approaching this all wrong, I have the following models setup:

The `User` model has many `Questions`, a `Question` belongs_to a `User`

This means I can easily do: `u = User.last.questions` and see all of the questions associated with the user last added.

Following this, I have a `Payment` model that belongs_to a `Question`. A `Question` has_one `payment` meaning I can easily do `u = User.last.questions.last.payment`, getting the payment details from the question last added by the last added user (daft example perhaps!).

**Now the bit that is confusing me**

I have a model called `PaymentOption` which is used to populate a drop down list, for different prices, the `PaymentOption` belongs_to a `Payment` and a `Payment` has_one `PaymentOption`

**This is all working correctly, but the only way for me to find out the details of the payment option, such as the amount, would be to do something like this:**

`payment_amount = PaymentOption.find(User.last.questions.last.payment.payment_option_id).amount`

**Ideally I would do something like this:**
`amount = User.last.questions.last.payment.payment_option.amount`

By doing it in the way I have, it is as good as doing two seperate queries, one to get the payment option ID and another to find a detail relating to that particular payment option. Surely there is a better way to approach this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

To clarify my answer, I have included the schema for Payments and PaymentOptions

```
create_table "payment_options", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "amount"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "title"
  t.boolean  "user_accessible", default: true
  t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
end

create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "token"
  t.integer  "question_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  t.integer  "payment_option_id"
end

add_index "payments", ["payment_option_id"], name:    "index_payments_on_payment_option_id"
add_index "payments", ["question_id"], name: "index_payments_on_question_id"
```

Comment: Are you sure that amount is an attribute of `payment_option`, and not of `payment`?  Can you show the model file for payment?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information - Thank you

Comment: I think your schema & associations are either flat-out wrong or else inefficient.  What are the associations between `payment` and `payment_option` in their respective model files?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, the model associations are "PaymentOption belongs_to a Payment and a Payment has_one PaymentOption" I think my schema may have become slightly messed up after a migration or two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is you problem:

> I have a model called PaymentOption which is used to populate a drop
>   down list, for different prices, the PaymentOption belongs_to a
>   Payment and a Payment has_one PaymentOption

You said you've setup `Payment` has_one `PaymentOption` and `PaymentOption` belongs_to `Payment`. But in the schema described in the end `Payment` has a `payment_option_id`.

In this case, `Payment` belongs_to `PaymenteOption` and not the opposite. See [this example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) in the Rails Guide. `Account` has `supplier_id` so `Supplier` has one `Account` and `Account belongs_to` Supplier.

Your models should be like this:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :payment_option

end

class PaymentOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment # Or even has_many :payments
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This works so far as that it enables me to access the Payment Option details like this: `amount = User.find(3).questions.find(50).payment.payment_option.amount`. I will check through my migrations to see what could have caused the schema to be incorrect. Thinking about it, based on your answer, has_many would be more correct - having changed my model does that now make my schema correct?